# Unable to install on Dell with Killer WiFi

Tags: wifi

The **Killer WiFi hardware** found in many current Dell laptops is supported from Kernel 5.2 upwards but your newest release has 5.0.

When I installed LinuxMint I got around this by connecting to my iPhone via bluetooth and using the mobile broadband to download the latest Kernal and then everything works.

I can connect my phone via bluetooth to Hera but the mobile broadband does not appear in Networks as an option. Is it even possible for the user to update the kernel in Hera? and is there a way around the bluetooth wifi connection. I would really like to try out elementary OS properly.
Paul

Answer (score 1):

I currently have 2 DELL with Killer wifi card and they have always works with the version of elementary OS 5.0 and 5.1 and with kernel 4.X and the new 5.X ( `5.0.0-37-generic` for elementary OS Hera)

I think you did not check the option 
**install third party software for graphics and wifi hardware and additional media formats** during the window **Update and other software**

[image: Update and other software]

If you want update your Kernel in elementary Hera you can do that with this command

```
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

Comment: I was running off the live USB so perhaps that is the problem - thanks

Comment: Indeed, I think that the test via USB wifi cards do not operate. I did not test by activating the Wifi on live CD (choice test) on my DELL XPS.