# WiFi issue on Elementary OS Lenovo

Tags: wifi, networking, lenovo

I have been heard that Lenovo devices commonly face the WiFi issue in Ubuntu. Is the same problems are there in Elementry OS?

Thank you. I have tried the way in **GitHub** but it is not working well. Still, I can't connect WiFi or use it. **This says there are no device for wifi**.

If you guys can solve this issue that would be a great help for Linux lovers like me.

Comment: Did you check the option **install third party software for graphics and wifi hardware and additional media formats** during the window **Update and other software** when you install elementary OS : for your help : https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/21471/19360, If yes maybe is the driver, it's better if you give us the model of your wifi card with : `sudo lshw -C network`

Comment: yeah, I tried and succeed ...because I have Realtek driver.